# d3: hovering over words in text at the same time highlighting the corresponding bars and make word in text clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Dear Stackoverflow community

I am still a great beginner when it comes to D3 and JavaScript. I could implement my code in a way that I can upload a text file, transfer to the content to the next page, and render the bar charts. However I still do not have any clue how to realize the following function. Whenever the user hover over a word in the text the corresponding bar should be highlighted in a certain color. Also, how can I make the words in the text clickable. I hope you can help me out. I could not find anything appropriate on the internet to solve these problems.

Thank you very much.
Here is my code:
Loading the text file:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>File Upload</title>

        <style>
            .filepond--root {
                font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto,
                Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji',
                'Segoe UI Symbol';
            }
            .filepond--drop-label {
                color: #000033;
            }
            .filepond--panel-root {
                background-color: transparent;
                border: 1px solid #6666ff;
            }

            .filepond--panel-root {
                background-color: #e5e5ff;
            }

            .filepond--label-action {
                text-decoration-color: #a7a4a4;
            }

            /* the color of the focus ring */
            .filepond--file-action-button:hover,
            .filepond--file-action-button:focus {
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.125em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
            }

            h2 {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 17px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #939393;
                line-height: 0.1em;
                margin: 10px 0 20px;
            }

            h2 span {
                background:#fff;
                padding:0 10px;
            }


        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <input type="file" class="filepond" id="fileInput">


    <h2><span>OR</span></h2>

    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="textArea1">Paste your text here</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="textArea1" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick ="myFunction()">Submit</button>


    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>
    <script>
        FilePond.parse(document.body);

        document.getElementById("fileInput").addEventListener("change",getF);
            var res;

             function getF(event) {

                 // check if textarea empty

                     var input = event.target;

                     readContentFile(input.files[0]).then(content => {
                         res = content;
                         getContent(res);
                     }).catch(error => console.log(error));


             }


        function readContentFile(file){


                var reader = new FileReader();

                return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    reader.onload = event => resolve(event.target.result);
                    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
                    reader.readAsText(file, 'ISO-8859-1');
                })
        }

        String.prototype.trim = function() {
            return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        };

       function getContent(file) {
               localStorage.setItem("fileContent", file);
           return file;
       }

        function myFunction(){
            if (!(document.getElementById("textArea1").value.trim() == '')) {
                localStorage.setItem("fileContent", document.getElementById("textArea1").value);
            }
                 location.href="AnotherPage.html";
        }

    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The page with the graph and the text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AnotherPage</title>

    <style>
        .row {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
        [class^='col'], [class*=' col'] {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        #blockText{
            border-left: 1.5px solid black;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="rectsBlock">
            <svg id="barchart"></svg>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="blockText">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    var textContent, textDiv;
   textContent = document.createTextNode(localStorage.getItem("fileContent"));
    textDiv = document.getElementById("blockText");
    textDiv.appendChild(textContent);

    // extracting words

   // var engPattern = /\w+/g;
        var engPattern = /\b[^\d\W]+\b/g;

       //var krPattern = /[\uac00-\ud7af]|[\u1100-\u11ff]|[\u3130-\u318f]|[\ua960-\ua97f]|[\ud7b0-\ud7ff]/g;

        var res = localStorage.getItem("fileContent").match(engPattern);

       // console.log("Sprache"+localStorage.getItem("fileContent").match(krPattern))

        var unique = res.reduce(function (a, b) {
            if (a.indexOf(b) < 0)
                a.push(b);
            return a;
        }, []);

        function removeOneLetterElem(arr){
            var index = 0;
            for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
                if(arr[i].length ===1 && arr[i]!=="a"){
                    console.log("Wert ist "+arr[i]);
                    index = arr.indexOf(arr[i]);
                    console.log(index);
                    arr.splice(index,1);
                }
            }
        }
       removeOneLetterElem(unique);

        console.log(unique);

        //function distinguishLang(lang){
        //}

    console.log("Value is"+document.getElementsByClassName("bar").textContent);

    // percentages

    var arrNums = [];

    generatePercentages();
    function generatePercentages(){
        var arr = [];

        for(var i = 0;i<unique.length;i++){
            arr.push(Math.floor((Math.random()*100) + 1));
        }
        arrNums = arr;
    }


    // building json

    var jsonData;
    var wordset ={};

    function buildJson(){
        var words = [];
        var word, val, wordElem;

        wordset.words = words;
        for(var i=0;i<unique.length;i++){
        word = unique[i];
        val = arrNums[i];
        wordElem={
            "word":word,
            "value":val
        };

        wordset.words.push(wordElem);
        }
        jsonData = JSON.stringify(wordset);
    }

    buildJson();
        // bar chars
   console.log(wordset.words);


    var margin = {top: 5, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 90},
        width = 600- margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 1500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#rectsBlock").select("#barchart")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,width]);
    var y = d3.scaleBand().range([height,0]);

    var g =  svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    wordset.words.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.value-b.value;
    });
    x.domain([0, d3.max(wordset.words, function(d){
        return d.value;})]);
    y.domain(wordset.words.map(function(d){
       return d.word;
    })).padding(0.2);

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0));


   var bars = g.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(wordset.words)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class","bar")
        .attr("x",0)
        .attr("height",y.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.word); });

        bars.transition()
        .duration(50)
        .delay(function (d, i) {
            return i * 20;
        })
        .attr("width", function(d){
            return x(d.value);
        })
        .attr("fill","#1bf0c0");


        g.selectAll(".text")
        .data(wordset.words)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .transition()
        .duration(50)
        .delay(function (d, i) {
            return i * 20;
        })
        .attr("class","label")
         .attr("y",function(d){
            return y(d.word)+y.bandwidth()-1;
        })
        .attr("x",function(d){
            return x(d.value)+3;
        })
        .attr("dy",".12em")
        .style("font-size", "11px")
        .text(function(d){
            return d.value+"%";
    });

    bars.attr("id",function(d,i){
        return i;})
        .on("mouseover",function(d){
            console.log("Printing words "+d.word);
                d3.select(this)
                    .style("fill", "brown")

        }).on("mouseout",function(d,i){
            d3.select(this).style("fill","#1bf0c0");
        });


    d3.select("#blockText")
        .on("click", function(){
        alert("clicked");
    });

</script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

These are sample text files for testing :

https://ufile.io/xz9wd

Comment: I had some problems with formatting. I am very sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach to do that:

1. Instead of appending the whole text as content to the `#blockText`, creating [span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) elements with the **corresponding word** stored as key would make it easier to add events to.

   ```
   res.forEach(function (word) {
       var span = document.createElement('span');
       span.textContent = word + ' ';
       span.setAttribute('data-key', word);
       textDiv.appendChild(span);
   });
   ```
2. Adding events: I'm using jQuery to add the `mouseover`, `mouseout` and `click` events to the above added `span`s. If you're not planning on including jQuery, you can always assign [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the newly created spans.

   ```
   $('div#blockText span[data-key]').on('mouseover', function () {
       var key = $(this).data('key');
       d3.select("#rectsBlock").select("#barchart").select('svg rect[data-key='+key+']').style('fill', 'brown');
   }).on('mouseout', function () {
       var key = $(this).data('key');
       d3.select("#rectsBlock").select("#barchart").select('svg rect[data-key='+key+']').style('fill', '#1bf0c0');
   }).on('click', function () {
       console.log("Clicked word: " + $(this).data('key'));
   });
   ```

Fork of your JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/j4qav07u/

Inline snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AnotherPage</title>

    <style>
        .row {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
        [class^='col'], [class*=' col'] {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        #blockText{
            border-left: 1.5px solid black;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="rectsBlock">
            <svg id="barchart"></svg>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="blockText">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    var textContent, textDiv;

  var fileContent = 'As ending of freedom of movement is central to the deal, some MPs have been calling for the government to publish the white paper for its post-Brexit immigration bill before next weekís meaningful vote.\n\nThe government has told those MPs this is not likely to happen. On Wednesday, the home secretary, Sajid Javid, said it was ìstill his intentionî to publish it this month ñ a choice of words opposition MPs met with groans and sighs.\n\nDefending the delay, Javid told MPs: ìItís worth keeping in mind that this is the biggest change in our immigration system in four decades. Itís important that we take the time and we get it right.î\n\nJavid also said freedom of movement would end, ìdeal or no dealî ñ in effect saying that while it was a key part of the deal, it was not strictly tied to what May was offering.\n\nHe also said MPs had been given glimpses of what the post-Brexit immigration system would look like.\n\nThe government is proposing a single immigration system that treats migrants from EU countries in the same way as those from non-EU countries. Highly skilled workers who want to live and work in Britain will be given priority.\n\nHowever, the government says the ability of people from abroad to deliver services and student exchange programmes will form part of future trade agreements.';


   textContent = document.createTextNode(fileContent);
    textDiv = document.getElementById("blockText");
    //textDiv.appendChild(textContent);

    // extracting words

   // var engPattern = /\w+/g;
        var engPattern = /\b[^\d\W]+\b/g;

       //var krPattern = /[\uac00-\ud7af]|[\u1100-\u11ff]|[\u3130-\u318f]|[\ua960-\ua97f]|[\ud7b0-\ud7ff]/g;

        var res = fileContent.match(engPattern);

    res.forEach(function (word) {
         var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.textContent = word + ' ';
          span.setAttribute('data-key', word);
         textDiv.appendChild(span);
        });
        
        $('div#blockText span[data-key]').on('mouseover', function () {
         var key = $(this).data('key');
          d3.select("#rectsBlock").select("#barchart").select('svg rect[data-key='+key+']').style('fill', 'brown');
        }).on('mouseout', function () {
         var key = $(this).data('key');
          d3.select("#rectsBlock").select("#barchart").select('svg rect[data-key='+key+']').style('fill', '#1bf0c0');
        }).on('click', function () {
         console.log("Clicked word: " + $(this).data('key'));
        });
        
       // console.log("Sprache"+localStorage.getItem("fileContent").match(krPattern))

        var unique = res.reduce(function (a, b) {
            if (a.indexOf(b) < 0)
                a.push(b);
            return a;
        }, []);

        function removeOneLetterElem(arr){
            var index = 0;
            for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
                if(arr[i].length ===1 && arr[i]!=="a"){
                    //console.log("Wert ist "+arr[i]);
                    index = arr.indexOf(arr[i]);
                    //console.log(index);
                    arr.splice(index,1);
                }
            }
        }
       removeOneLetterElem(unique);

        //console.log(unique);

        //function distinguishLang(lang){
        //}

    //console.log("Value is"+document.getElementsByClassName("bar").textContent);

    // percentages

    var arrNums = [];

    generatePercentages();
    function generatePercentages(){
        var arr = [];

        for(var i = 0;i<unique.length;i++){
            arr.push(Math.floor((Math.random()*100) + 1));
        }
        arrNums = arr;
    }


    // building json

    var jsonData;
    var wordset ={};

    function buildJson(){
        var words = [];
        var word, val, wordElem;

        wordset.words = words;
        for(var i=0;i<unique.length;i++){
        word = unique[i];
        val = arrNums[i];
        wordElem={
            "word":word,
            "value":val
        };

        wordset.words.push(wordElem);
        }
        jsonData = JSON.stringify(wordset);
    }

    buildJson();
        // bar chars
  // console.log(wordset.words);


    var margin = {top: 5, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 90},
        width = 600- margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 1500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#rectsBlock").select("#barchart")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,width]);
    var y = d3.scaleBand().range([height,0]);

    var g =  svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    wordset.words.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.value-b.value;
    });
    x.domain([0, d3.max(wordset.words, function(d){
        return d.value;})]);
    y.domain(wordset.words.map(function(d){
       return d.word;
    })).padding(0.2);

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0));


   var bars = g.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(wordset.words)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class","bar")
        .attr("x",0)
        .attr("height",y.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.word); });

        bars.transition()
        .duration(50)
        .delay(function (d, i) {
            return i * 20;
        })
        .attr("width", function(d){
            return x(d.value);
        })
        .attr("fill","#1bf0c0");


        g.selectAll(".text")
        .data(wordset.words)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .transition()
        .duration(50)
        .delay(function (d, i) {
            return i * 20;
        })
        .attr("class","label")
         .attr("y",function(d){
            return y(d.word)+y.bandwidth()-1;
        })
        .attr("x",function(d){
            return x(d.value)+3;
        })
        .attr("dy",".12em")
        .style("font-size", "11px")
        .text(function(d){
            return d.value+"%";
      });

    bars.attr("id",function(d,i){
        return i;}).attr('data-key', function (d) { return d.word; })
        .on("mouseover",function(d){
            //console.log("Printing words "+d.word);
                d3.select(this)
                    .style("fill", "brown")

        }).on("mouseout",function(d,i){
            d3.select(this).style("fill","#1bf0c0");
        });


    d3.select("#blockText")
        .on("click", function(){
        alert("clicked");
    });

</script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank youuu soo sooo much. It has helped so much. I have learned something new today. You can indeed combine d3 and jquery. Does the attribute data-key has a certain meaning? And I also encounter these nested notations for the first time div#blockText span[data-key] and 'svg rect[data-key='+key+']'. What do they mean concretely? Thank youu very much.

Comment: Happy to help. Oh I thought you were aware of DOM selectors (as that is some pretty good code you've written there) and so I didn't think of explaining them in my answer. Anyway, `data-*` is a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) assigned to the `span` storing information (word) in this case which is then later used within the mouse events as `.data(key)`. To know how selectors work (i.e. `div#blockText span[data-key]`), reading [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) will give you a clear idea.

Comment: Right now when you hover over a word that word can appear near the bottom and in that case it is not visible to the user. Is there a way to dynamically scroll to that specific bar? I tried many ways, but it did not work out. I still do not have a clear thought how to combine jquery and d3.

Comment: I tried to do this, but it seemed completely wrong.

var element = d3.select("#rectsBlock").select("#barchart").select('svg rect[data-key='+key+']');
        console.log("Wert ist "+element);
        element.scrollIntoView();

Comment: You can't use jQuery's `scrollIntoView` on SVG elements. That's a whole new (and a major) thing to be answered right here. One idea would be to get the position of the bar in the chart and using jQuery animate, adjust the scrollTop value and animate the scrolling. I'm sorry this is too much to answer here.